# bundle install fails for custom spree gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gemfile

I have a spree app running where I am using number of gems to solve some of my purposes.

I am using a gem [spree social](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_social), [spree reviews](https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_reviews) and a couple more. I had my code and It was working well. But since I have pulled the code, I am getting error like below

> Could not find gem 'spree_social' in source at `vendor/gems/spree_social`.
>   Source does not contain any versions of 'spree_social'

Here's how I've mentioned my gems

```
 gem 'spree_wishlist' , :path => File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '/vendor/gems/spree_wishlist-2.2.0')
 gem 'spree_reviews',  :path => File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '/vendor/gems/spree_reviews')
 gem 'spree_social',  :path => File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '/vendor/gems/spree_social')
 gem 'spree_gift_card',  :path => File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '/vendor/gems/spree_gift_card')
 gem 'stringex'
 gem 'spree_auth_devise',  :path => File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '/vendor/gems/spree_auth_devise-3.0.6')
```

Someone please help me out in this.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to do in Gemfile:

`gem 'spree_social', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_social', branch: 'master'`. Then run `bundle install`.

Comment: that's one thing which I want to try but someone else has pushed this code and my worry is there could be some reason he has used it that way and hence I am not risking it

Comment: Download gems from dithub and try to copy them into `vendor/gems/spree_social`. Don't know for sure, but I think it should work.